# How to convert solidity return uint and use it on frontend using Etherjs

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, javascript

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Lending {
    // calculating the value of loan on the basis of collateral
    uint LTV = 20;
    mapping(address => uint) public addressToAmt;
    mapping(address => uint) public addressToTime;

    function modifyLTV(uint _newVal) public {
        LTV = _newVal;
    }

    // 0.00002(RBTC)*10^8=2000RSAT
    function calculateLoanAmt(
        uint _collateralVal
    ) internal pure returns (uint) {
        uint num = _collateralVal * 20;
        uint denom = 100;
        return num / denom; // It is returning the value in RSAT
    }

    function requestForLoan(uint _collateralVal) internal returns (uint) {
        uint eligibleAmt = calculateLoanAmt(_collateralVal);
        addressToAmt[msg.sender] = eligibleAmt;
        addressToTime[msg.sender] = block.number;

        return eligibleAmt;
    }

    function calculateInterest() public view returns (uint) {
        uint amt = addressToAmt[msg.sender];
        uint block_difference = block.number - addressToTime[msg.sender];
        uint no_of_days = block_difference / 144;
        uint rate_of_interest = 2739; // 2739 x 10^(-5) , we manage the decimals below
        uint total_interest_non_decimal = amt * no_of_days * rate_of_interest;
        uint total_interest = total_interest_non_decimal / 100000;
        uint total_payable_amount = amt + total_interest;
        return total_payable_amount;
    }
    function fetchLoanDetails() public view returns (uint,uint){
       uint time =  block.number-addressToTime[msg.sender]; 
     return ( addressToAmt[msg.sender],time);
   }
   function resetValue() internal{
        addressToAmt[msg.sender] = 0;
        addressToTime[msg.sender] = 0;}
}
```

I'm trying to receive the fetchLoanDetails() and calculateInterest() function's return using ethers and display it on react frontend but nothing is displayed on the screen. tried to use the formatEther & parseEther functions but both gave errors.
On the console when I'm printing the values it is giving (...)n (4072465n).

How to convert these return uint values into integers and display them on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

as docs https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/ say there is a method .toNumber() in BigNumber

Answer (score 0):

First, your `fetchLoanDetails()` function returns a tuple , so you have to handle it.
Secondly, your `calculateInterest()` functions returns a BigInt type object. You can handle it by just converting it to string.
example:

```js
//bigIntVar 4072465n
bigIntVar.toString() //4072465 wei
```

If you want to get ethers as a uint you can use

```js
//bigIntVar 4072465n
const balEth = ethers.formatEther(bigIntVar);
balEth.toString() //0.000000000004072465 ether
```